# Does failing to build the "dell-laptop-natty-dkms" module on 12.04 matter?

Tags: kernel, dkms

I'm using 12.04 on my Dell laptop. I got a "system problem detected" message with title `dell-laptop-natty-dkms 1.5.1: dell-laptop-natty kernel module failed to build` .

I'm not sure what this means. Wasn't Natty an older version? Do I need to worry about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to worry about this. It's a DKMS version of the `dell-laptop` module for Natty (11.04), and it *seems* to me from a Google search that it was only available via PPA.

Since the 12.04 kernel series (3.2) is not available for Natty, the DKMS build fails. It's harmless, and I would remove it with `sudo apt-get --purge remove dell-laptop-natty-dkms` to get rid of the warning.